# Почему не работает простая функция на JS?

Tags: javascript

```
function addressBook(query) {
  let phoneBook = [];

  query = query.split(' ');

  switch (query[0]) {
    case "ADD": {

      let note = "";
      note.concat(query[1] + ": "); // добавляем имя

      query[2].split(',').forEach(number => {
        note.concat(number + ", "); // добавляем номера телефонов
      });

      note = note.substring(0, note.length - 2); //  убираем последние запятую и пробел

      phoneBook.push(note);
    }

    case "SHOW": {
      let modifiedPhoneBook = [];

      phoneBook.forEach(note => {
        if (note.split(' ').length > 1) {
          modifiedPhoneBook.push(note); // если есть хоть один номер телефона
        }
      });

      modifiedPhoneBook.forEach(number => {
        console.log(number);
      });
    }
  }
}

addressBook("ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03");
addressBook("SHOW");
```

На каком строчке у меня ошибка и почему? Я хочу вывести все записи из телефонной книги, но ничего не выводится.

---

> 3. Адресная книга
>
> В этом задании необходимо реализовать функцию, через которую можно
> управлять телефонной книгой.
>
> Для управления телефонной книгой нужно реализовать три команды:
>
> ADD — добавляет контакт
>
> REMOVE_PHONE — удаляет номер
>
> SHOW — возвращает содержимое телефонной книги
>
> addressBook('ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03');
>
> addressBook('ADD Ivan 555-10-02');
>
> console.info(addressBook ('SHOW'));
>
> // Вывод:
>
> // ["Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-03, 555-10-02"]
>
> addressBook('REMOVE_PHONE 555-10-03');
>
> addressBook('ADD Alex 555-20-01');
>
> addressBook('SHOW');
>
> // Вывод:
>
> // ["Alex: 555-20-01", "Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02"]
>
> addressBook('REMOVE_PHONE 555-20-01');
>
> addressBook('SHOW');
>
> // Вывод:
>
> // ["Ivan: 555-10-01, 555-10-02"]
>
> Гарантируется, что функция будет вызываться корректно, только со
> списком перечисленных команд. Корректность входных данных проверять не
> нужно.
>
> Имя команды пишется большими буквами, параметры разделяются одним
> пробелом.
>
> Гарантируется уникальность добавляемых телефонов.
>
> Команда ADD
>
> Добавляет контакт в телефонную книгу со списком телефонов. Телефоны
> перечисляются через запятую. Если такой контакт существует, то команда
> пополняет список телефонов контакта.
>
> ADD Name phone1,phone2
>
> Команда REMOVE_PHONE
>
> Удаляет телефон из телефонной книги. Если телефон успешно удалён, то
> функция должна вернуть true. Если такого телефона в телефонной книге
> не существует, то возвращается false.
>
> REMOVE_PHONE phone1
>
> Команда SHOW
>
> Возвращает массив контактов с их телефонами. Массив содержит строчки
> вида: "Имя: Телефон1, Телефон2". Массив должен быть отсортирован по
> имени контакта. Телефоны идут в порядке добавления их в телефонную
> книгу. Контакт с пустым списком телефонов не должен возвращаться.
>
> ADD Contact2 phone4,phone3
>
> ADD Contact1 phone1
>
> ADD Contact1 phone2
>
> SHOW
>
> [
>
> "Contact1: phone1, phone2",
>
> "Contact2: phone4, phone3"
>
> ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при `ADD` создаётся всегда новый массив и потом в него одна запись добавляется, и потом он уничтожается сразу. Массив должен быть внешний.

А при `SHOW` функция ничего не возвращает, хотя в задании это требуется.

Comment: Еще `note.concat(query[1] + ": ");` валяется в коде и не влияет на исходную строку.

Comment: вооот, спасибо, не заметил сразу